# Two users, same machine, same python installs, one can't import paramiko without UserWarning, module already imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko, hashlib

When running following code, user without error reports normal termination.

```
python -c "import paramiko"
```

User with error reports termination (note, no exception) with the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py:7: UserWarning: Module _hashlib was already imported from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so, but /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hashlib-20081119-py2.7-linux-i686.egg is being added to sys.path
  import pkg_resources
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py:7: UserWarning: Module hashlib was already imported from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py, but /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hashlib-20081119-py2.7-linux-i686.egg is being added to sys.path
  import pkg_resources
```

Both users have the same PYTHONPATH, PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. There are no virtual environments on this machine. All .pyc files have been removed on computer and error persists.

Python Version: 2.7.11
OS: CentOS 32 bit el6

`pip freeze` reports `hashlib==20081119` and `cryptography==1.7.2` and `paramiko==2.1.1`

Does anyone have any insight into this problem? I do not understand why one user can perform this task without error, while the other cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by reinstalling paramiko with pip, ignoring caches and site-packages

Comment: Accept your answer, for the benefit of future generations.